# How to find the latest created files?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-explorer, filesystems

Suppose I want to find all files created the last 10 minutes (for instance), how can I do that?

Both with GUI and CLI are welcome.

Comment: Hi. Could you edit your post and share what you've tried so far, what the results were and what you were expecting?

Answer (score 1):

The below will recursively search a directory for any files created in the past 10 minutes.

```
#Directory you want to search
$Directory = "c:\"

# Time frame in minutes (Must be a negative value.)
$TimeFrame = -10      

Get-Childitem -Path $Directory -Recurse | Where {$_.CreationTime -gt (get-date).AddMinutes($TimeFrame)}
```

Comment: +1 or as oneliner if this is a one time thing: `gci c:\ -r -file | where creationtime -gt (get-date).AddMinutes(-10)`

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to limit the search to specific file formats? Say pdf and jpeg?

Comment: @JDoeDoe - look at `Get-Help Get-ChildItem` - especially the `-FIlter` and `-Include` parameters. [*grin*]